# Does mochiweb can play m3u8 stream?

Tags: erlang, http-live-streaming, mochiweb

I use lighttpd to play http live stream, it works well. I want to use mochiweb to play it in order for high performance， is it feasible ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. An http live streaming server is a standard http server. It serves static content with no logic stored in the server, all information about the stream is in the files that it serves.